# Send message from iPhone without open MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios5, sms, phonegap-plugins, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I have made one application, In my application I want to send message on some mobile no.
I know, this is done using MFMessageComposeViewController.

but, can we send message without open the MFMessageComposeViewController ?

Can we use MFMessageComposeViewController in background and send message on some mobile no ?

any one has idea then pls help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we said before (you can search here in StackOverFlow), user interaction *has to be called*.
What if your application send spam messages ? What if it send message to a plateform you own with taxed messages ?
So the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ShareKit without UI  but you cant do that for mail or SMS

Comment: Is this possible in phone gap?